# Center an auto-width div?

Tags: css, width, alignment

I'm having trouble because I have a div I want to center and what I have
usually been told to do is this:

```
width: 700px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

the trouble is, this is for if you want the div to be a fixed width. I want the div
to adjust its size based on the text in the div, and still be centered. I tried:

```
width: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

but this didn't work. It stretches the div to fill up the screen when I do this.

Anyone know what to do here?

Comment: give your div a certain width and better align your text as you want !! div will remain according to the position you give, the text will get in center, if you text-align:center;

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid - giving my div a fixed width

Comment: @DanK can you paste you html as well or create a fiddle, which will help to understand easily.

Comment: you should provide html of the div and its container and the css of that also

Answer (score 46):

for parent block or body - `text-align:center`;
for centerd block- `display:inline-block`;

```
.center {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}
    
<div class="center">
    <p contenteditable="true"> write text </p>
</div>
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/RXP4F/

[Content Editable MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

Comment: not working. what is contenteditable ?
and body tag is not relevant to question.

Comment: How can it NOT work, when you go to the demo and it DOES work :D

Comment: Working answer. Instead of setting text align to body, I prefer to use parent div and set its text alignment.

Answer (score 14):

have you tried the approach shown here?
http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm

basically.
put your content inside a floated div
put that floated div within another floated div

put left: 50%, position relative on outer div
put left: -50%, position relative on inner div

finally, nest everything in one more div with overflow:hidden

```
.outermost-div{
    background-color: blue;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

.inner-div{
   float:left;
   left:50%;
   background-color: yellow;
   position: relative;
}

.centerthisdiv {
   position:relative;
   left: -50%;
   background-color: green;
   float:right;
   width:auto;
}
```

here is my jsfiddle demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/wbhyX/1/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to me ^^ Thank you @shinjin

Comment: Definitely the best answer, as when you stack blocks they do not get centered. Only the div gets centered

Answer (score 12):

Use margin: 
`0px auto; and display: table;`
There are example:
https://jsfiddle.net/da8p4zdr/

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try CSS `display:table-cell` or `display:table`

Comment: Right - I've tried the display:table property but that removes the columns that I have within my div...

Answer (score 3):

Try this structure.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="center_div">

    </div>
</div>



.container{
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.center_div{
   position: relative;
   left: -50%;
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - but I think b/c I have columns within my "center_div" that did not work well with that CSS.  My container div is #Body and the div I'm trying to center with a width:auto is my #Content.

Answer (score 1):

zloctb's answer on Aug 30 '13 at 4:14 actually worked in principle but was incomplete. If you want your element width to be 'auto' based on the contents within it AND centered within its parent BUT with the contents inside the CHILD element left-aligned, do the following (because it really is the simplest way):

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent div.child {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

(Obviously, if you just wanted everything strictly centered, you would not need the code for the child element.)

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

use `table`, it could be easier to style. Then add `div` into the `tr`

Comment: I actually have columns that are within my div, and the columns stretch out to fill the screen because of the width:auto.  The columns are of a fixed width - but the parent div is width:auto

Comment: I have tried the display: table - but b/c I have columns within my div it doesn't work.  The columns are eliminated and only one appears in the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

.outer-container { 
            position: relative;
            left: 50%;
            float: left;
            clear: both;
            margin: 10px 0;
            text-align: left;
        }

.inner-container {
            background: red;
            position: relative;
            left: -50%;
            text-align: left;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Centering an element horizontally can get a little weird, as the functionality isn't very intuitive. Really, you need to play games with `text-align:center;` and `margin:auto,` and you'll need to know when to use which.

For example, if I want to center the contents of an element (raw-text), including buttons and inputs, I can use `text-align:center`.

```css
.text-center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center" style="border:1px dashed blue;padding:6px;" >
  My contents are centered! That includes my <input placeholder="inputs" /> and my <button>buttons.</button>
</div>
```

If we add other elements to our container, those elements will have their width forced to 100%. This helps us emulate that it is centered because technically, at 100%, it is centered! Silly, isn't it?

```css
.text-center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center" style="border:1px dashed blue;padding:6px;" >
  My contents are centered! That includes my <input placeholder="inputs" /> and my <button>buttons.</button>
  <p style="background-color:orange;width:auto" >Even though my width is explicitly defined as "auto," I still have 100% width! What gives?!</p>
</div>
```

If your width property IS defined though, then you can use the `margin: auto` style to center it within the parent.

```html
<div style="margin:auto;border:1px solid black;width:300px;" >
  I am centered!
</div>
```

You need to determine which solution is best for you. I wish I could help more, but it is hard to know what solution will best fit your needs when you haven't provided the HTML for you problem!

Either way, I hope [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/jbsr9pe9/) helps clear things up!